# How can I make this script responsive?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, widget

I have this news widget from a site that isn't responsive. When I access the site with a smartphone, this part of the widget goes out of the screen a little. What can I do to make that part stay aligned with its container? Here's the code of the widget:

```
<article class="four columns">
    <div class="panel">
        <h3 style="text-align:center">Notícias</h3>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.noticiasagricolas.com.br/widget/noticias.js.php?subsecao=84,13,2,97,15&largura=350px&altura=595px&fonte=HelveticaNeue-Light&tamanho=10pt&cortexto=000000&corlink=006666&qtd=10&output=js"></script>             
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: could you provide a demo link ?

Comment: You need to provide enough code to fully replicate the issue, otherwise we cannot help you